# Authentication required Unable to login after up gradation to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: login, authentication

Recently i have upgraded my system to Ubuntu 22.04 but i am not able to login where i get below messages while system boot up

***Message 1 ) [0.133920] ipmi:dmi; Base addresss is zero,assuming no IPMI interface***

After this message for few minutes, system shows another message

***Message 2 )Authentication required  System policy prevents medication of network settings
for all   users***

and system does not let to enter password and  I can't use the system anymore.

But if i turn on my WiFi and restart the system, it shows me message 1 while system boot up and it lets me enter the password during message 2 and i can use system.

Pl help i want to login  to system without using WiFi

I Have been facing problem since two days after up-gradation to Ubuntu 22.04.

Thanks in advance

Rohan

Comment: 22.04 is not released yet, all images before GA are unsupported

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot login via the GUI, you can always try control-alt-F1 to open a console window.

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this error and this is how I resolved it.

1. Switch from GUI to terminal(tty).**Ctrl + Alt + F3 or F4...6**
2. Enter your username and the password.
3. Try updating packing in the new system.

   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

If any error occurs try to follow instructions as indicated.In my case I run
`sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`
then I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade -y` again.

4. Reboot your system.

   `sudo reboot now`

It will update your packages and fix broken ones.

Comment: I had the same problem (Sept 2023) and a variation of this solution worked for me too. However, I also got a screen stating "A problem has occured and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator". I couldn't get in the terminal so I booted into recovery mode to do the updates. DNS was not working so I edited /etc/resolv.conf and added nameservers. Then proceeded with the rest of the fix and it worked.